# Best way to implement CDN in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpmodule

I need to implement CDN in an ASP.NET project. The best Idea I could come up with is creating a custom HttpModule which will handle the **PostRequestHandlerExecute** event. I'm replacing all the static URLs domain with the CDN's zone url before the response is sent to the client.

Here's my module code:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;

public class CdnModule : IHttpModule
{
    public static string CdnUrl;
    public CdnModule()
    {
        CdnUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CdnUrl"];
    }

    public String ModuleName
    {
        get { return "CdnModule"; }
    }

    // register handlers 
    public void Init(HttpApplication app)
    {
        app.PostRequestHandlerExecute += PostRequestHandlerExecuteHandler;
    }
    private void PostRequestHandlerExecuteHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        if (response.ContentType == "text/html")
        {
            response.Filter = new UrlFilter(response.Filter);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() { }
}

public class UrlFilter : Stream
{
    private Stream _responseStream;
    StringBuilder _responseHtml;

    public UrlFilter(Stream inputStream)
    {
        _responseStream = inputStream;
        _responseHtml = new StringBuilder();
    }

    #region Filter overrides

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override void Close()
    {
        _responseStream.Close();
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        _responseStream.Flush();
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }

    public override long Position { get; set; }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        return _responseStream.Seek(offset, origin);
    }

    public override void SetLength(long length)
    {
        _responseStream.SetLength(length);
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        return _responseStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    #endregion


    //Here I'm replacing URLs

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        var html = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, offset, count);

        //replace relative UploadFile urls with absolute CDN zone
        html = html.Replace("\"/UploadFile/", "\"" + CdnModule.CdnUrl + "/UploadFile/");

        buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);

        _responseStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Below piece of code is responsible for intercepting and modifying the response text:

```
    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        var html = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, offset, count);

        //replace relative UploadFile urls with absolute CDN zone
        html = html.Replace("\"/UploadFile/", "\"" + CdnModule.CdnUrl + "/UploadFile/");

        buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);

        _responseStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
```

Am I doing it right? or is there any better way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: We use the microsoft [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) to do this for us.

Comment: @Liam how you do this? appreciate any pointers!

Comment: It's complicated, read though the docs. But basically no need to code it yourself, it's works on top of IIS as a separate install and allows you to re-write URLs based on several criteria.

Comment: We're already using URL Rewrite module but we don't want the requests to hit our server for any static resource, it should point to CDN zone url by default!

Comment: yep, you can do that too

Comment: I'm not getting it, can you please help me out with any pointers?